# Question concerning Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ and Lagrange's remainder theorem

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Consider the Taylor polynomial of 5th degree of $\sin(x)$ centered at zero:
$$
T_5(x) = x - \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + \dfrac{x^5}{5!}.
$$
Lagrange's remainder theorem gives us an expression for the remainder $R_5$, namely

$R_5 = \dfrac{-\sin(\xi)}{6!}x^6$  for some $\xi\in \mathbb{R}.$ If I'm not mistaken, this means that

$\sin(x) =  x - \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + \dfrac{x^5}{5!} -\dfrac{\sin(\xi)}{6!}x^6$  and since $(\forall x\in \mathbb{R})\space -1\leq \sin(x) \leq  1$ there exists some

$a\in [-1, 1]$  s.t.  $\sin(x) =  x - \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + \dfrac{x^5}{5!} -\dfrac{a}{6!}x^6$. This is probably the point where I misunderstood

something because
wouldn't that imply that we could just attempt to find this $a\in[-1,1]$ and thus would obtain a very  simple expression  for $\sin(x)?$ Is it possible to find this $a$?

Comment: And *how* do you plan to find $a$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos my question should rather be whether it is possible to find this $a$.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Wrong. The remainder *is* the error.

Comment: Generally speaking, there is no practical way to find $a$.  If there were, we'd have an exact formula for $\sin x$, and would have no need to approximate it.

Comment: @saulspatz so just for my better understanding, there somewhere is this $a$ but it's almost impossible to find it?

Comment: It's not impossible to find it; it's $a=\frac{6!}{x^6}(\sin(x) - x + x^3/3! - x^5/5!)$. But the point is that this doesn't have a simple relationship with $x$. However, if you have information about the derivative of the function between $0$ and $x$, it can give you bounds on what $a$ can be; this is the utility of the remainder theorem.

Comment: @angryavian  I see that it is almost impossible to find it, but isn't there a incredibly small probability that you could find this $a$  since it's definite real number? I know that there are uncountably many of those in the interval $[-1,1]$ but if you say that  you can't  find it, wouldn't that contradict its existence?

Comment: @Sebastian As I mentioned in my comment, it's not impossible to find $a$; I gave an explicit expression for it.

Comment: @angryavian sorry, I misread your comment, thanks!